# Why is the time limit exceeding?

Tags: java, algorithm

Why is the code exceeding time limit? The problem is to find the longest palindrome in a given string. It works for the inputs I'm putting in, but only works for 90 out of 103 cases, and it just says time limit exceeded.

```
enter code class Solution {
public String longestPalindrome(String s) {
    String longest = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j <= s.length(); j++) {
            if (isPalindrome(s.substring(i, j)) && s.substring(i, j).length() > longest.length()) {
                longest = s.substring(i, j);
            }
        }
    }
    return longest;
}
public boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length()/2; i++) {
        if ((s.charAt(i)) != s.charAt(s.length() - i - 1))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Reverse the inner loop so you check substrings of decreasing length. Once you find a palindrome, it has to be the longest you will find. (Also, store the substring in a variable instead of continually recomputing it. And consider whether you need to use substring at all, given you then use charAt).

Answer (score 2):

Brute force algorithms usually fail on LeetCode. The thing is we have to come up with efficient low-complexity algorithms for medium and hard questions.

Here is a bit more efficient solution that'd pass through:

```
class Solution {
    public String longestPalindrome(String baseString) {
        String longest = "";
        for (int index = 0; index < baseString.length(); ++index) {
            String oddString = extend(baseString, index, index);
            String evenString = extend(baseString, index, index + 1);
            if (oddString.length() > longest.length())
                longest = oddString;
            if (evenString.length() > longest.length())
                longest = evenString;
        }
        return longest;
    }

    private String extend(String baseString, int indexA, int indexB) {
        for (; 0 <= indexA && indexB < baseString.length(); --indexA, ++indexB) {
            if (baseString.charAt(indexA) != baseString.charAt(indexB))
                break;
        }
        
        return baseString.substring(indexA + 1, indexB);
    }
}
```

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-palindromic-substring/discuss/). There are plenty of accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) and explanations, efficient algorithms, as well as asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup> in there.

#### If you are preparing for [interviews](https://leetcode.com/problemset/top-interview-questions/?listId=wpwgkgt):

- We would want to write [bug-free](https://www.codegrip.tech/productivity/tips-to-write-bug-free-code-during-interview/) and [clean](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-write-cleaner-code-during-onsite-interviews) codes based on standards and conventions (e.g., [c](/questions/tagged/c)<sup>[1](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/cplus/cstyle.html), [2](https://users.ece.cmu.edu/%7Eeno/coding/CCodingStandard.html)</sup>, [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)<sup>[1](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html), [2](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/coding-standards)</sup>, [java](/questions/tagged/java)<sup>[1](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html), [2](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf)</sup>, [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)<sup>[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions), [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/?redirectedfrom=MSDN)</sup>, [python](/questions/tagged/python)<sup>[1](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)</sup>, [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)<sup>[1](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html)</sup>, [go](/questions/tagged/go)<sup>[1](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments)</sup>, [rust](/questions/tagged/rust)<sup>[1](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0/style/)</sup>). Overall, we would like to avoid anything that might become controversial for interviews.
- There are also other similar [platforms](https://www.quora.com/Which-one-is-better-HackerRank-or-LeetCode), which you might have to become familiar with, in case you'd be interviewing with specific companies that would use those platforms.

#### If you are practicing for [contests](https://leetcode.com/contest/)<sup>[1](https://cses.fi/book/book.pdf)</sup>:

- Just code as fast as you can, almost everything else is very trivial.
- For [easy](https://leetcode.com/problemset/all/?difficulty=Easy) questions, brute force algorithms usually get accepted. For interviews, brute force is less desired, especially if the question would be an [easy](https://leetcode.com/problemset/all/?difficulty=Easy) level.
- For [medium](https://leetcode.com/problemset/all/?difficulty=Medium) and [hard](https://leetcode.com/problemset/all/?difficulty=Hard) questions, about 90% of the time, brute force algorithms fail mostly with [Time Limit Exceeded](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overcome-time-limit-exceedtle/) (TLE) and less with Memory Limit Exceeded (MLE) errors.
- Contestants are ranked based on an algorithm explained [here](https://leetcode.com/discuss/general-discussion/468851/New-Contest-Rating-Algorithm-(Coming-Soon)).

Answer (score 1):

Wells it's because your algorithm is too slow.

Going through all `i,j` pairs takes `O(n^2)` time where `n` is string length, and getting a sub-string takes `O(substringLength)` which is `O(n)` on average, so runtime of your algorithm is `O(n^3)`.

You didn't specify the limits on string length but theres more effiecient ways to solve this problem, using Manacher algorithm you can get runtime of `O(n)`, or if limit is not too high you can get `O(n^2)` with dynamic programming